# how to get note value from contact book in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to have my application which gets values from contact book from Android Phone.

I have tried People, `ContactContracts.Data`, `ContactContracts.Contact.Data` and 
`ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` to read value of NOTE value from Phone book. 
But Can't get successed .Please help me.

Comment: Please See my answer and if answer is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use below Code for Get Note Value from Contacts.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

for (int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
    System.out.println("Hello");
    String contactId = cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    String note = null;
    String[] columns = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE };
    String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
    String[] whereParameters = new String[] {
            contactId, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
    Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, columns, where,
            whereParameters, null);

    if (contacts.moveToFirst()) {
        String rv = contacts.getString(0);
        note = rv;
    } else{
        String rv = contacts.getString(i);
        note = rv;
    }
    contacts.close();
    System.out.println("Note is: " + note);

    cursor.moveToNext();            
}
```

Comment: how can i get the other values like phone, name etc 

String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
I'm trying to get value like this but it's not working

Comment: Why the part of "contacts.getString(i)" ?